# Data on Vapour Pressures of Silicone Oils

Tags: vapor-pressure, viscosity, organosilicon-compounds

I am trying to find specific information on vapour pressure of silicone oils with different viscosities which I have used in some experimental work. Is there a chemical databook where this information can be found, or is estimated?

The vapour pressures should differ for oils of different viscosities because their molecules will be of different molecular weights.

The data sheet I found online from the manufacturer for 2 cSt silicone oil merely states that the oil has vapour pressure which can be measured in hectopascals.  This is not specific enough as that could still be several hundreds of pascals and I need to quantify how low it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since each manufacturer uses a proprietary mix of silicones, there is no general rule. You'll need to rely on manufacturer's data. Some companies **do** give actual vapor pressure at specific temperatures, e.g.,*Silicone 704*: ["Vapour pressure @ 25°C  1x10<sup>-9</sup> mbar"](https://www.plasmadiam.com/oils-and-lubricants/silicone-fluids).

Why not contact the manufacturer directly, instead of asking a third party?